# JQuery split on multi-select options

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the JQuery split() function on values selected in a multiple select list.  Something is not working on my split line:

Code:

```
$('.chosen-select').click(function(){
   alert("selected: " + $('.chosen-select').val());

   var categories = $('.chosen-select').val().split(',');
   alert("categories: " + categories[0]);
});
```

When I load the page, the first alert() appears with comma-separated values like ( abc,def,ghi ) based on my selections, but not the second alert.  Not sure what I am missing.

Ideas?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Firstly, `split()` is a JavaScript function - nothing to do with jQuery. Secondly, both your `alert()` are missing the closing bracket. Lastly, use the `change` event on `select` elements instead of `click` as it then will also fire when the user changes the selection via the keyboard.

Comment: my first alert line in my code is missing a closing paren and semi-colon.  That is from copy-pasting.  It is in my code.

Comment: The second one is also missing it.

Comment: Can you add your HTML as well?

Comment: how do I add code?  Never works for me pasting into comments.  Should I edit, my first post and add it there?

Comment: I just read that a multi-select box/list creates an array, not a string.  I did not know that.

Comment: Yes, edit your first post (edit link is under the tag)